# Jquery Datepicker - How to hide clear and "step" buttons?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I inherited a project for a client. The client doesn't want to have the "clear" buttons and the "step" (which increments the day/month/year by one) shown anymore. I can't figure out how to make these disappear. They appear to be imbedded in the input field and are not a background image or anything like that. I am guessing this is control via date picker. How can I hide these? Thank you very much! Here is a screen shot (copy link to enlarge)

[image: Here is a screen shot]

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

What you have mentioned is not jQuery UI datepicker, it is a simple **`HTML5 date`** input type.

```
<input type="date"/>
```

*This is the default appearance of the `HTML5 datepicker`*, which cannot be changed, if you're not interested better move on to [**`jQuery UI datepicker`**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).